# In java, how do i obtain the value by which the slider changed?

Tags: java, swing, jslider

I have a `JSlider` with a minimum of 0 and maximum of 100. Its current value is 0.

At runtime how do I get every value that slider is moved across? For example, with my current code if I change the slider very fast from 0 to 16, it shows like output like:

```
0
1
2
3
4
7
16
```

It skipped 8 to 15 because I moved the slider directly from 7 to 16 very fast. But I do not want that to happen. I want each and every value to be printed that the slider came across in its movement.

I also want the program to capture the last value the slider took in its movement.

This is my code:

```
p1.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() 
{ 
   @Override public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) 
   { 
      if (p1.getValueIsAdjusting())
      { 
        System.out.println(p1.getValue()); 
      } 
   } 
});
```

Can anyone explain why this isn't printing every value?

Comment: Please share the code you've already written and highlight where the problem  is. We can then provide advice and fixes.

Comment: p1.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
         @Override
         public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
               if(p1.getValueIsAdjusting()){
                System.out.println(p1.getValue());
               }
       }
     });

Answer (score 3):

Most people have the opposite problem in that they just want the final JSlider value and not the intermediate values.

There's no guarantee in Swing that your change listener is going to be called for every intermediate value.

Keep the previous JSlider value, determine the final value, and calculate the intermediate results yourself.

Comment: Calculating the difference was my thought as well, but it won't capture rapid back and forth movement completely.

Comment: @aclear16:  Why not?  In your question, you go from 7 to 16.  The intermediate values are 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, and 15.

Comment: What if I go from 7 to 16 to 12 and then to 8? It isn't going to catch all the intermediate values if I do it quickly enough. Oh, and it isn't my question...

Comment: @aclear16: You're calculating the intermediate values, not Swing.  The values are 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8.  If it's not your question, why are you curious?

Comment: You are assuming that in the middle of a quick change, it will catch the max number, which it may not. Hence, your method may not catch every number. And why shouldn't I be curious? Isn't the spread of knowledge kind of the point of this whole site?

Comment: @aclear16: And what's wrong with my assumption.  You have to stop the slider to change direction.  That gives Swing the opportunity to execute the listener.  You're correct in that Swing doesn't guarantee that the listener will be triggered on any intermediate value.  Feel free to suggest another method.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the `getValueIsAdjusting()` is responsible for the behaviour you see. It is there to avoid needless code execution while the users drags the slider.

If you remove the `if` clause, you should see every value.

Answer (score 0):

> At runtime how do I get every value that slider is moved across?

Since a `JSlider` is effectively 1 dimensional, I'd suggest:

1. Get the starting value
2. Get the end value
3. get every value in between from the model used for the slider.

The result of point 3. would seem to be the answer to your question.

Of course, since it is such a trivial answer, it then raises the $64 question of..

*What application feature are you trying to offer the user?*  Explain it as you might explain it to an end user, for better answers.